# Cec-client is very slow and gives segmentation fault on Raspberry Pi

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault

I am using a Raspberry Pi and I want to be able to change the input of the TV using cec-client.

I tried these two scripts:

```
echo "scan" | cec-client -s -d 1
```

and

```
echo "as" | cec-client -s -d 1
```

When I tried them on a monitor without having a TV, they ran fine, although obviously didn't do anything meaningful.
Afterwards I tried them on a TV. Scanning usually takes around 1 minute and gives back proper info but at the end also says "segmentation fault". The "as" command always resulted in segmentation fault without switching the input, and it took multiple minutes. I tried updating the firmware of the LG TV, but it did not help. Later tried it on a Philips TV, I still had these problems. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling cec-client. Tried restarting the Raspberry Pi. Nothing worked so far.

Comment: Bug is discussed here in the official thread: https://github.com/Pulse-Eight/libcec/issues/476